# CS-Cart new template for Product Filters block

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

I want to add a new template option for the product filters block.

So far, I have copied the existing original.tpl from:

```
templates\blocks\product_filters
```

and put it into:

```
templates\addons\my_changes\blocks\product_filters
```

then I've renamed the file to: example.tpl and edited the top line of the file to be:

```
{** block-description:example **}
```

This basic process has worked for other blocks but not for this product filters one. The only options available in the template list are 'Original', and 'Horizontal filters'.

Is there something special I need to do to make my new template show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates available to be used by blocks are defined at schema, which is located at "app/schemas/block_manager/blocks.php" file.

Usually schema contains a path to a directory containing all templates that can be used by a block, like it's done for the "products" block:

```
'templates' => 'blocks/products',
```

Which makes block manager search templates at `design/themes/[theme name]/templates/blocks/products` directory.

Unfortunately, by some reasons the schema of the "product_filters" block is inconsistent compared to other block schemas - it contains the list of a concrete templates to be used:

```
'templates' => array(
    'blocks/product_filters/original.tpl' => array(),
    'blocks/product_filters/selected_filters.tpl' => array(),
    'blocks/product_filters/horizontal_filters.tpl' => array(),
),
```

Because of that, no directory scan is being performed at a moment of determining a list of templates available for a block.

This is why the approach you're using worked for other blocks but not for "product_filters".

The solution for you is simple - you should create a "app/addons/my_changes/schemas/block_manager/blocks.post.php" file with the following content:

```
<?php
$schema['product_filters']['templates'] = 'blocks/product_filters';

return $schema;
```

After that please clear the cache and make sure that the "my_changes" add-on is installed and enabled.

Thanks for pointing out this problem, we'll fix it in an upcoming releases.

Comment: Thanks for this info! One more thing- I am actually using the home page product filters block, which seems to have a different list to the standard one. Is there another schema file I need to add for this?

Comment: @user500665 You just need to replace the "product_filters" with "product_filters_home" at the code example given above.